# Setting environment variables osx 12.0.1

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-monterey

I need some help to set environment variables on osX 12.0.1.
I tried to edit .bash_profile (it doesnt exist), .zprofile and also a pllist approach.
What irritates me, is that % env is not working in Terminal.
Any hints for a newbee? Any help appreciated! :)

Comment: Firstly what shell are you running?  (type `ps` in the terminal to see either `zsh` or `bash`).  Then once you know that you can edit either `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I run bash as I learned. .bashrc is not in my home directory. Should I create it?

Comment: Yeah create it..  It's unusual you are running bash as zsh has been the default for a few versions of macOS.

Comment: yeah, I created the file and and also .bash_profile and added the environment variables I needed to the ladder, now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You can set the environment variable in ~/.zprofile

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

This works fine for macOS Monterey